# How deal with Datetime fields in MS SQL Server while using Codeigniter active record library?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, datetime, activerecord

What I'm trying to achieve is something like:

```
$since_yesterday = new DateTime();
$since_yesterday->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$this->db->where('LastModified >= ', $since_yesterday);
return $this->db->get('Table1')->result_array();
```

> Message: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Build a DateTime PHP object and use it to filter MS SQL Server rows. I'm using 'mssql' driver and I can connect and execute queries, I just don't know how handle DateTime data conversion from CI Active Record and MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DateTime::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to convert the object into string representation. You can use the pattern `Y-m-d H:i:s` to get MySQL style date:

```
$since_yesterday = new DateTime();
$since_yesterday->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
// $since_yesterday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') yields '2012-11-26 23:22:41'
$this->db->where('LastModified >= ', $since_yesterday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Comment: Thanks @Salman. BTW when I query the database the datatime fields are like 'Sep  5 2012 04:24:22:393PM', hwo I can change that format to a Y-m-d H:i:s' format?

Comment: The fields are MS SQL Server DateTime type, but CI Active Record return them in the format 'Sep 5 2012 04:24:22:393PM', and what I want is change that format, may be if not a PHP DataTime, at least something more clean, like '2012-10-5 14:24:22'. Thanks again.